# how to unittest function in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Just starting with angular unit testing and want to know something abt testing functions in controllers. I found some samples of how to unit test with karma but they all have the functions like this:

```
$scope.someFunction= function(){....}
```

Is it possible to just define the function without putting it on the $scope?

Comment: Unit testing is about testing the API / external interface of your component; *"does this component do what I expect it to do when I do something with it"*. If there is no external access to the function then it is not testable however you can test the parts that use it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could, but that way functions would be like "private" functions, only accessible from inside your controller since controller are usually not accessible from other modules (controllers, directives or services).

The only way you would access a controller directly is when using them as API for a custom directive, see for example [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for directive [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: Controllers are accessible by the templates bound to them

Comment: Only their $scope, not private functions

Comment: It was in response to your *"since controller are usually not accessible from other modules"* statement